# Which is the best framework can be used for developing native android apps?

Tags: java, android, spring

Lets say we are building a online shopping app like amazon,flip-kart,etc .In this case implementing a framework while building app would be very good practice. I want to know famous frameworks developers uses nowadays to build such kind app. Lets assume back-end engine is developed by restful service.

Please share your thoughts about the [Spring Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) framework.

Comment: Apache Cordova is one of the best platform for creating the mobile application because u need to create only one application which can be deployed in various platforms .

Comment: Heavily opinion based.

Comment: Thank u Ragesh !!  but Apart from the advantages what are the disadvantages of using Apache Cordova ? any performance issues or can i get look and feel same like native android platform. My application doesn't have very fancy stuffs but it will call restful API to Google endpoints and fetches results and displays in a list view. May be later point we need to implement payment gateway. Cordova well fit for this kind of app ?

Comment: ! ya ..Gecko ... Whats your opinion ?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some Android ready frameworks available.
According to the Eclipse Open Source Developer Report 2012, 60 percent of open source developers writing Android or iOS apps use only the official SDK. Among those who use cross-platform frameworks, the choices, ranked from first to last were:

- jQuery Mobile (28.6 percent)
- PhoneGap (17.9)
- Sencha Touch (7.9)
- Dojo Mobile (4.9)
- Titanium (2.8).

You can have a look at 
**SproutCore:** This HTML5-driven framework offers a "clean" MVC architecture, and emphasizes performance optimization and scalability.

Comment: Thank you @Mallikarjuna !!! out of curiosity where did you got these statistics .. Any references.

Comment: Yes You can refer here  [link](https://www.linux.com/news/embedded-mobile/mobile-linux/612366-15-android-ready-application-development-frameworks-)